# Why are all styles lost when the js snippet is executed from a bookmark?

Tags: javascript, html, css, bookmarklet

I need an in-page editor to take notes when reading a web page, so I write a little javascript snippet:

```
document.body.innerHTML+="<div style='position:fixed;\
top:10px;right:10px;width:300px;height:50%;background:#ccffcc;\
z-index:9999'><p contenteditable='true' style='font-size:150%;\
width:100%;height:100%'></p></div>";
```

to add a floating editor on the page I am reading.

When I execute this in Chrome's console, everything works fine. But when I add a bookmark: `javascript:[the-above-js-code]`, and click it from bookmark bar, all css are gone from the page.

What is happening? And what can I do to avoid this?

EDIT:
When I change the snippet to:

```
var frag = document.createDocumentFragment();
var myDiv = document.createElement("div");
myDiv.innerHTML="<div style='position:fixed;top:10px;right:10px;width:300px;height:50%;background:#ccffcc;z-index:999'><p contenteditable='true' style='font-size:150%; width:100%;height:100%'></p></div>";
frag.appendChild(myDiv);
document.body.appendChild(frag);
```

It works in the bookmarklet. Looks if I re-write body's innerHTML, the stylesheets are not applied. But it still baffles me why the first snippet works in Chrome console.

EDIT：
I don't know why, but after I append this to the bookmartlet, it works.

```
void(0);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works because `javascript:` URL will make the browser render the result of the expression. The result of your first script is just plain HTML without any CSS (it's also not following any external links).

You can test it by executing `javascript:x = 'hello'` in your address bar.

The behavior is different when your script returns *undefined* which void(0) does. In this case browser won't redirect to the new content so both `javascript:x = 'hello';void(0);` and `javascript:x = 'hello';return undefined;` does nothing.